# Scroll List view on the tap of the Button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to scroll List view with the tap of the button.

How to get this type of functionality in the list view builder.

Note: The list is coming from API so the Length might be getting changed.

[Here is Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5Woc.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the working sample of what you need below.

```
class WidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetTestState createState() => _WidgetTestState();
}

class _WidgetTestState extends State<WidgetTest> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _scrollToTheNextItemView(
      {ScrollDirection scrollDirection = ScrollDirection.forward}) async {
    if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirection.forward) {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels <
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        await _scrollController.animateTo(
            _scrollController.position.pixels + 100,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.easeOut);
      }
    } else {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels >
              _scrollController.position.minScrollExtent &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        await _scrollController.animateTo(
            _scrollController.position.pixels - 100,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.easeOut);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Button Scroll"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () => _scrollToTheNextItemView(
                  scrollDirection: ScrollDirection.backward)),
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onPressed: _scrollToTheNextItemView)
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 120,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            controller: _scrollController,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: List.generate(
                20,
                (_) => Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 14),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum ScrollDirection { forward, backward }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this sample simple as cake

**Ui;**

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(onPressed: () => scrollToLeft(), child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left)),
                    FlatButton(onPressed: () => scrollToRight(), child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 80,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: listLength,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: ((ctx, i) {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.teal ,
                      width: _width,
                      child: Card(child: Center(child: Text("Item $i"))),
                    );
                  })),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Functions;

```
  scrollToRight(){
    if(scrollWidth <= _controller.offset){
      setState(() {
        scrollWidth = _width * baseScrollPoint * move;
        move++;
      });
      _controller.animateTo(scrollWidth, duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    }
  }

  scrollToLeft(){
    if(scrollWidth > 0){
      setState(() {
        move--;
        scrollWidth = scrollWidth - (baseScrollPoint* _width);
      });
      _controller.animateTo(scrollWidth, duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
    }
  }
```

Variables;

```
  ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
  final double _width = 50.0; // single item length
  final listLength = 20;
  final int baseScrollPoint = 3; // every click will move this much 
  double scrollWidth = 0.0;
  int move = 1;
```